# Dash does not get focus when maximized window open at the back

Tags: unity, unity-dash

This has been asked [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218093) but it doesn't seem to have a fix. In Ubuntu 14.04, when a maximized window is open and you open the dash, you won't able to have focus on the dash. User events such as click will be carried on the maximized window and not the dash.

This might be a known bug, but do we have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Is the window maximized or full-screen? And is your system updated? The question you linked to is from April 2014, so my thinking is that this could be an old bug that has been fixed with an update to Unity.  I am running 14.04 with Unity, and have never had this problem. My other guess is that you are missing a driver. If it is a driver issue, try updating or reinstalling your graphics driver.

Comment: I update regularly using the software updater. It only happens sometimes when the window is maximized.